# How to use date_diff for two adjacent sessions using BigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, datediff, date-difference

I'm trying to calculate average hours between two adjacent sessions using the data from the following table:

| user_id | event_timestamp | session_num |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2021-04-16 10:00:00.000 UTC | 1 |
| A | 2021-04-16 11:00:00.000 UTC | 2 |
| A | 2021-04-16 13:00:00.000 UTC | 3 |
| A | 2021-04-16 16:00:00.000 UTC | 4 |
| B | 2021-04-16 12:00:00.000 UTC | 1 |
| B | 2021-04-16 14:00:00.000 UTC | 2 |
| B | 2021-04-16 19:00:00.000 UTC | 3 |
| C | 2021-04-16 10:00:00.000 UTC | 1 |
| C | 2021-04-16 17:00:00.000 UTC | 2 |
| C | 2021-04-16 18:00:00.000 UTC | 3 |

So, for user A we have

```
1 hour  between session_num = 2 and session_num = 1,
2 hours between session_num = 3 and session_num = 2,
3 hours between session_num = 4 and session_num = 3.
```

Same for the other users:

`2, 5` hours for user B;

`7, 1` hours for user C.

The result I expect to get should be the arithmetic average of this date_diff(HOUR).

So, `avg(1,2,3,2,5,7,1)` = 3 hours is the average time between two adjacent sessions.

Any one have an idea what query can be used so the date_diff function would be applien only for anjacent sessions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The average hours between sessions for a given user is most simply calculated as:

```
select user_id,
       timestamp_diff(max(event_timestamp), min(event_timestamp), hour) * 1.0 / nullif(count(*) - 1, 0)
from t
group by user_id;
```

That is, the average time between sessions for a user is the maximum timestamp minus the minimum timestamp divided by one less than the number of sessions.

Comment: Thank you Gordon!
This query works great, but I wasn't able to understand how exactly does it work.
You are using nullif function to check if the session_num is adjacent to each other, right?
So what is "count(*)" expression means here? How exactly proximity check works in this query?

Comment: `count(*)` is counting the number of events.  There is no need for proximity check -- as the answer explains. The average is the maximum minus the minimum divided by the number of "pairs".

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
with mytable as (
  select 'A' as user_id, timestamp '2021-04-16 10:00:00.000' as event_timestamp, 1 as session_num union all
  select 'A', '2021-04-16 11:00:00.000', 2 as session_num union all
  select 'A', '2021-04-16 13:00:00.000', 3 as session_num union all
  select 'A', '2021-04-16 16:00:00.000', 4 as session_num union all
  select 'B', '2021-04-16 12:00:00.000', 1 as session_num union all
  select 'B', '2021-04-16 14:00:00.000', 2 as session_num union all
  select 'B', '2021-04-16 19:00:00.000', 3 as session_num union all
  select 'C', '2021-04-16 10:00:00.000', 1 as session_num union all
  select 'C', '2021-04-16 17:00:00.000', 2 as session_num union all
  select 'C', '2021-04-16 18:00:00.000', 3 as session_num
)
select avg(diff) as average
from (
  select
    user_id,
    timestamp_diff(event_timestamp, lag(event_timestamp) OVER (partition by user_id order by event_timestamp), hour) as diff
  from mytable
)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, Sergey!
How can I apply this query to big data when there are a huge number of users and their sessions?

Comment: Gordon's answer will be better in terms of resources used.